# I am building a calculator in flutter. This is my code for the same. I am getting this error regarding the intialization

Tags: flutter

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor:Colors.pink[300],
      ),
      home: Calculator(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class Calculator extends StatefulWidget {
  const Calculator({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CalculatorState createState() => _CalculatorState();
}

class _CalculatorState extends State<Calculator> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Calculator'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
     body:Container(
       child: Column(
         children:<Widget> [
           Expanded(
             child:Container(
               padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
               alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
               child:Text(text,
               style: TextStyle(
                 fontSize: 50.0,
                 fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
               ),
               ),
             )
           ),
             Row(
               children: [ 
                 customElevatedButton('9',),
                 customElevatedButton('8',),
                 customElevatedButton('7',), 
                 customElevatedButton('+',),              
               ],    
             ),
             Row(
               children: [ 
                 customElevatedButton('6',),
                 customElevatedButton('5',),
                 customElevatedButton('4',), 
                 customElevatedButton('-',),              
               ],              
             ),
             Row(
               children: [ 
                 customElevatedButton('3'),
                 customElevatedButton('2'),
                 customElevatedButton('1'), 
                 customElevatedButton('X'),              
               ],               
             ),
             Row(
               children: [ 
                 customElevatedButton('C',),
                 customElevatedButton('0',),
                 customElevatedButton('=',), 
                 customElevatedButton('/',),              
               ],              
             ),
         ],
       ),
     )
    );   
  }

  Widget customElevatedButton(num) {
    return Expanded(
      child: RaisedButton(  
                padding:EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
                color:Colors.pink[100] ,             
                onPressed:(){
                  operation(num);
                },
                child:Text(num,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40.0),             
                ),
                ),
    );
  }
String text='';
void operation(clickedButt)
{
  String result;
  int first,second;
  String opp;
  if(clickedButt=='C'){
    result='';
    text='';
  }
  else if(clickedButt=='+'||clickedButt=='-'||clickedButt=='X'||clickedButt=='/'){
    first=int.parse(text);
    result='';
    opp=clickedButt;
  }
  else if(clickedButt=='='){
    second=int.parse(text);
    result='';
    if(opp=='+'){
      result=(first+second).toString();
    }
    else if(opp=='-'){
      result=(first-second).toString();
    }
    else if(opp=='*'){
      result=(first*second).toString();
    }
    else if(opp=='/'){
      result=(first/second).toString();
    }
    else{
      result=int.parse(text+clickedButt).toString();
    }
    
  }
  else{
    result=text+clickedButt;
  }
  setState(() {
    text=result;
  });
}



}
```

The error is:
Error: Non-nullable variable 'first' must be assigned before it can be used.
Error: Non-nullable variable 'opp' must be assigned before it can be used.

I already initialized those variables before the if statement. Why am I getting this error?
Actually the text variable is should also be initialized within the operation() function. But then again the error is showing in calculator widget.

Comment: You can add `late` in the beginning of the declaration of these variables (e.g. `late String oop;`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With dart null safety you cannot assign null to the `String opp;`

The error says you have initialized the variable `opp;` with null value. To avoid that either,

1. change `String opp;` to `String? opp;`
2. use late keyword before opp as `late String opp;` (in this case you have to make sure that you are assigning opp variable before is is used otherwise it will throw late initialization error again)
3. assign value to opp variable at the declaration as `String opp = "someString";`